# WSO2 API Manager and XACML integration not working

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to integrate the latest version of `wso2 API Manager (1.6.0)` with the `wso2 XACML module`. I've found and followed step by step the very useful [article](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/02/use-of-wso2-api-manager-to-validate-fine-grained-policy-decisions-using-xacml/).
Unfortunately the PDP refuses the authorize my request even if I remove all my policies from the PAP and publish no policy to the PDP.

Is their a configuration somewhere I'm missing ?
 I'm get the following output

`[2014-03-05 19:05:37,052]  WARN - RequestCtxFactory No Namespace defined in XACML request and Assume as XACML 3.0
[2014-03-05 19:05:37,058] ERROR - EntitlementMediator org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: User is not authorized to perform the action
[2014-03-05 19:05:37,059]  INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = User is not authorized to perform the action`

Comment: Please have a policy and use the inbuilt 'try it' tool to test the policy. This will help you to figure out any issues in the XACML policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no policies in the PDP means that PDP would return `Not Applicable` decision. Therefore PEP of the API manager would think `Not Applicable` as a deny decision. In XACML there is concept called `Deny based PEP` What that means, all result except `permit` are considered as deny. Therefore to test, you can add some policy with Permit rule and verify.  Such as following

`<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicyId="PermitPolicy" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0">
   <Target></Target>
   <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Permit-Rule"></Rule>
</Policy>`

Also it would be helpful,  if you can enable the debug logs in the entitlement component and check..  Because then you can see the XACML request and response messages.

Add following in to log4j.properties file

`log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement=DEBUG`

You can check [this](http://soasecurity.org/2014/02/26/how-to-wso2is-troubleshooting-wso2-identity-server-1/) for more on enabling debug logs

Once you got the request and response.   you verify what has gone wrong.. Also you can there is a tryit tool whether you can test the policies.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for your quick and efficient support.
I've added your "permit" rules and was able to access my backend system after a successful 
policy validation. This means that the loop is closed and that my very simple policy of yesterday was the root of the problem. 
I have to review in detail how these rules are setup & defined.
Thanks again for your help
Regards
Vpl

[2014-03-06 19:03:11,637] DEBUG - EntitlementPolicyInvalidationCache My Hash code of Policy cache is : 1
[2014-03-06 19:03:11,637] DEBUG - EntitlementPolicyInvalidationCache Shared Hash code of Policy cache is : 1
[2014-03-06 19:03:11,638] DEBUG - SimplePolicyCollection Matching XACML policy found PermitPolicy
[2014-03-06 19:03:11,638] DEBUG - EntitlementBaseCache Cache : $**local**$.PDP_DECISION_CACHE  is populated with new entry in tena
nt domain : carbon.super
[2014-03-06 19:03:11,639] DEBUG - EntitlementEngine XACML Response : Permit
[2014-03-06 19:03:11,641] DEBUG - EntitlementMediator Entitlement Decision is : Permit
[2014-03-06 19:03:11,643] DEBUG - EntitlementMediator User is authorized to perform the action
[2014-03-06 19:03:11,644] DEBUG - EntitlementMediator OnAccept sequence is not defined.

Comment: Great to hear that you got it work...  Also If you wish to learn more on XACML and Entitlement feature, Please refer this blog.. http://xacmlinfo.org/  it contains lot details..  If above answer it correct, You can accepted it.. :)